# Copying data from one table of Excel to another if data of one column matches to data of another table

Tags: excel

Excel Table1 has 2 columns "productName","productCode". Column "productCode" is empty.  Table2 also has 2 columns "productName","productCode".  Now if "productName" in table2 matches that of "table1", data in "productCode" of table2 should be copied in "productCode" of "table1".

Comment: You may use `VLOOKUP()`, `XLOOKUP()`, `INDEX()/MATCH()`.

Comment: Kindly write full syntax. I am new to vba and all

Comment: Kindly read SO guidelines at Help Center. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask would be a good start

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach of your task. Presuming that Table1 is the name-code base.

Place this formula in the example I2.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@[Product Name]];Table1[#All];2;FALSE);"Unknown")
```

[image]